# RMarkdown - print() command results in out of page bound lines in kitted PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is there any way to avoid overshooting lines that go beyond the margin of a page if you knit a RMarkdown document to a PDF?

Illustration:

````
# RMarkdown file
    title: "xyz"
    author: "John Doe"
    date: "23 2 2021"
    output:
      pdf_document: 
        latex_engine: xelatex
          toc: true
          toc_depth: 5
     html_document: default
     mainfont: Times New Roman
     fontsize: 12

text
more text
```{r}
  print("This is a very long line illustrating my question that drives me nuts. It should include more text that is supposed line-break if it goes beyond specified margins.)

  a <- 10
  b <- sqrt(2)
 
  print(paste("This is also a use case that I am looking at right now. I want to print results in the PDF documents of a calcualtion and put it in context.", a, "divided by square root of 2 results in", (a/b))

 ```
````

Any way to force line breaks if text goes out of bound? I tried editing YAML headers in the Markdown file, creating preamble files and reference them in the YAML header, trying various latex engines to knit my document as PDF, defining margins for the PDF document, manually splitting long `print()` calls to span several lines in the source file and adhering to the max. number of characters per line, but all failed so far. HTML output seems to be just fine.

Would **highly appreciate any pointers** to already provided answers in the past, as I am sure that I am not the only one having experienced these kind of problems, but unfortunately I am unable to find a fitting solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potential solution is to change the width using '--listings' (per https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/text-width.html), e.g.

Create a file called "preamble.tex" in the directory where you are knitting and include the lines:

```
\lstset{
  breaklines=true
}
```

Then change the YAML and knit:

````
> --- title: "xyz" author: "John Doe" date: "23 2 2021" output:
>     pdf_document:
>         pandoc_args: --listings
>         toc: true
>         toc_depth: 5
>         includes:
>             in_header: preamble.tex
>     html_document: default
>     mainfont: Times New Roman
>     fontsize: 12
> ---
> 
> ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
> knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
> options(width = 80)
> ```
> 
> text
> more text
> ```{r}
> print("This is a very long line illustrating my
> question that drives me nuts. It should include more text that is
> supposed line-break if it goes beyond specified margins.")
> 
> a <- 10 b <- sqrt(2)   paste("This is also a use case that I am
> looking at right now. I want to print results in the PDF documents of
> a calcualtion and put it in context.", a, "divided by square root of 2
> results in", a/b, sep = " ")
> ```
> 
> ## R Markdown
> 
> This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax
> for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on
> using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
> 
> When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that
> includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code
> chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
> 
> ```{r cars}
> summary(cars)
> ```
> 
> ## Including Plots
> 
> You can also embed plots, for example:
> 
> ```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
> plot(pressure)
> ```
> 
> Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to
> prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

[image: example_1.png]

### Edit

Another potential solution (what I usually do) is to output the RMarkdown as html using `options(width = 80)` in the {r setup} chunk, then convert the html to pdf with https://wkhtmltopdf.org/. If you're using macOS you can install wkhtmltopdf with homebrew (`brew install wkhtmltopdf`). The advantage to this approach is that it maintains any html-specific formatting i.e. you can use themes

Comment: Thanks Jared! Just noticed your post! I implemented the proposed solution and am just waiting for the knitted output. I'd be over the moon if this works. If not for whatever reason I'll try your neat trick of first rendering the HTML document and then converting it to a PDF document. Much appreciated!

Comment: I implemented both solutions at the time, so don't know which one of the two proposed solutions did the trick for me, but it worked like a charm!

Don't know why my prior attempt to add the preamble.tex file in the YAML header didn't do the trick for me before.

Again, much appreciated Jared :)

Comment: You're very welcome, but no need to thank me - pay it forward and answer some questions yourself (it's one of the best ways to learn)

Comment: As a beginner in R (mainly for an academic thesis), I am afraid that a lot of times, my solutions aren't very efficient or intuitive and I experience difficulties to formalize some problems so far, but as I am gaining further experience, I will definitely do so in the near future as I am getting more confident in my skills!